# update plugin version of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress plugin development, I have created a new small plugin (contact form) for test purpose only. Here is the link for plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-us-by-lord-linus/

I have started this plugin with version 0.8 and I am uploading 0.9.2 also, I have uploaded version 0.9.2 and I am able to download with the download link given on the wordpress repository, but I want to change the text for download link. now the text should be `Download version 0.9.2` instead of `Download version 0.8`. I was following the tutorial

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-publish-to-the-wordpress-plugin-repository/

For more details you can see the attached snap

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the readme.txt file, add

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 0.8
*/
?>
```

Comment: thanks widya, actually I was making a silly mistake, I was not updating the version number, so now I corrected this .